# Python - import from a file when a package has the same name

Tags: python, import

I did something silly when I started my python project: I named my main file project.py, and I stored a bunch of logic in a package that is also called project. Here's the directory structure:

```
project.py
project/
    other files
```

Here's the problem: Now I need to import the function main from project.py. But every time I try to import it, python tries to import the package instead of the module.

```
>>> from project import main
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'main'
>>> import project
>>> print(project)
>>> <module 'project' from 'c:\temp\project\__init__.pyc'>
```

Is there any way to fix this without renaming either the folder or the file?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but try "from project.project import main" ?

Comment: Is your `project` package (directory) in the same folder as your `project.py` module?

Comment: yeah, can you include your file/directory structure in the question?

Comment: Rename and refactor. Just that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, my solution is to move the logic from project.py to a new file:

```
project.py
project/
    main.py
```

contents of project.py:

```
import project.main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    project.main.main()
```

Then I can import project.main.main() directly.