# Can you ignore local files while importing in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I'm trying to import the mmap module in python, and due to the structure of the project that I'm working on, there is also a file called `mmap.so` in the same folder. For some reason, `import mmap` tries to import the `mmap.so` file and not the default python package. Is there a way to force-ignore files in the local dir? Thanks!

Comment: this link my help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15750955/python-import-from-a-file-when-a-package-has-the-same-name

Comment: this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893775/how-to-import-standard-library-module-instead-of-local-directory (probably even a duplicate...)